# Is there a way using C++ to get the number of video devices and their names inside linux?

Tags: c++, linux, video-processing, video4linux

Currently I use `ls -ltrh /dev/video*` to list all the video devices in the terminal, or `cat /sys/class/video4linux/video0/name` to display the name of that video device in terminal. I wonder is there a way to call some api in the C++ to get these information as well? Thanks.

Comment: [`/sys` filesystem](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html) is the API.

Comment: I guess the call you want is readdir_r